# Why does a SQL Server Query from NodeJS return a date object representing the day before the stored date?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

I am writing a NodeJS application which uses SQL Server as a data store. Node connects to SQL Server using the [mssql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql) native driver.

When I select a date object from the database with an empty time field, the date before the stored date is being returned.  For example, if the date field is 10/5/2005, then 10/4/2005 is returned.

Here are full details to reproduce:

First, create a table with a datetime column:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[testDate]    Script Date: 8/28/2014 8:11:35 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testDate](
    [testID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [testDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Then I can use this NodeJS code to demonstrate the problem.  It creates a new record in the testDate table, selects the new record, then uses console.log to output the date column.

This is the insert query:

```
insert into testDate (testDate) values ('10/5/2005')
```

Then run a select query:

```
select *from testDate
where testID = 1
```

Which will return the new row.  Something like this:

```
testID: 1   
testDate: 2005-10-05 00:00:00.000
```

The date has zero for the time stamp values--which is expected--and 10/5/2005 as the date--which also makes sense.  When this item is selected  using the mssql driver inside of Node, it turns into this:

```
Tue Oct 04 2005 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Basically, giving me 10/4/2005 instead of 10/5/2005.  I've tried this with multiple dates and am able to consistently replicate the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

For sake of completeness;

1. If I add a time stamp to the stored date value (12:00 or 12:01), a date object representing the correct date is returned properly in NodeJS.
2. If I select the same record using a different technology--I tried ColdFusion--the returned date object is correct.

---

Here is a full semi-runnable NodeJS code snippet which will insert a new record, select it, and output the date column to the console:

```
// import the db driver
var sql = require("mssql");

// set up the config to access the database
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'whatever',
    server: 'myserver.com', 
    database: 'testDB'
};

// Query to insert into database
var query= "insert into testDate (testDate) values ('10/5/2005')";
var query= query + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as testID";
console.log(query);

// create connection
var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    // when connection is made trigger off the first query
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(query, function(err, recordset){
        // result handler for query 1
        console.log(err); // undefined if everything is set up right
        console.log(recordset[0].testID); // the ID of the record we just inserted

        // select the item we just created from the database
        var query2= "select * from testDate where testID = " + recordset[0].testID;
        console.log(query2);

        // execute second query
        var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
            var request = new sql.Request(connection);
            request.query(query2, function(err, recordset){
                console.log(err); // undefined if everything is set up right
                console.log(recordset[0].testDate); // The Date; which is returning "Tue Oct 04 2005 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time" instead of Wednesday 10/5/2005
            });
        })

    });
})
```

At the moment, I am assuming I am doing something wrong as opposed to this being a bug in the mssql driver; but I'd be more than happy to open an issue on the mssql github account if no one can point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 2005-10-05 00:00:00.000 *is* 2005-10-05 20:00:00 GMT-0400. They represent the same moment, but on different timezones. I usually force the timezone and representation through moment.js. SQL Server has a [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) type that carries timezone offset info.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thanks, that gives me food for thought!  The question that comes to mind is why is the conversion made, and can I avoid it?  In reality I just need the date without the time.  It is weird for a user to enter one date, and later see the day before that.  I tried with a date column [instead of a DateTime column] and experienced the same 'conversion'.

Comment: Ever figure out the solution for this? This is my exact same problem.

Comment: @Ben_Coding This is what I did, generically: `datefield.setDate(datefield.getDate()+1)` Then I used a dateFormatter plugin to format the date before returning it `dateFormatter(datefield,'mm/dd/yyyy');` . Not the most elegant; but it worked for my purposes.